# CLR Regex for fractions

Tags: regex, clr

I need a CLR Regex for fractions or whole numbers and fractions where

`1/2` is correct 
`12 2/3` is correct too

and a minus sign can popup just before any number.

I first came up with `-?([0-9]* )?-?[0-9]+\/-?[0-9]+` but that seems to allow `2/7 12` too for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that regex would be in two parts, the (optional) whole number:

```
(:?-?\d+ )?
```

and the fractional part:

```
-?\d+/-?\d+
```

And we need to match the complete string; so:

```
^(:?-?\d+ )?-?\d+/-?\d+$
```

Testing a bit:

```
PS> $re=[regex]'^(:?-?\d+ )?-?\d+/-?\d+$'
PS> "1/2","12 1/2","-12 2/3","-5/8","5/-8"|%{$_ -match $re} | gu
True
```

However, this allows for `"-12 -2/-3"` as well, or things like `"1 -1/2"` which don't make much sense.

**ETA:** Your original regex works, too. It just lacked the anchors for begin and end of the string (`^` and `$`, respectively). Adding those make it work correctly.

Comment: tx, and you are right 1 -1/2 doesn't make sense, making it more complicated : -1/2 shoud be possible but 1 -1/2 not..

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar requirement, but I wanted to match decimal numbers as well.
I came up with the following regex

```
^-?(?<WholeNumber>\d+)(?<Partial>(\.(?<Decimal>\d+))|(/(?<Denomiator>\d+))|(\s(?<Fraction>\d+/\d+)))?$
```

Or just this if you don't want named groups

```
^-?\d+((\.\d+)|(/\d+)|(\s\d+/\d+))?$
```

To remove the decimal number from validating, it would be shortened to

```
^-?\d+((/\d+)|(\s\d+/\d+))?$
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

try this , just for single fraction and not the whole number

```
/^\d{1}\/?\d{1}$/
```